# Terminal user@location is using AppleTV and not computer

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, appletv

I opened terminal this morning after I turned on my computer from a shut down. Normally the terminal starts with `username@computerName`. This time it's `username@appleTVname`. I can't figure out how to switch back to my computer. A `pwd` is still showing me in my computer's main hard drive.

Hopefully this makes sense, but I've never had this happen before and am very much at a loss.